# Clear saveState on DataTable is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am having a few problems working with DataTable jQuery plug-in in my project. There are more than 20 tables using DataTable. Below is the javascript placed on every page that are using table with DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    pageSetUp();

    var responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column = undefined;

    var breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet : 1024,
        phone : 480
    };

    var otable = $('#datatable_fixed_column_GroupEnquiry').DataTable({
        "stateSave": true, // saves state using localStorage
        "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 hidden-xs'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12'<'toolbar'>>r>"+
            "t"+
            "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
        "autoWidth" : true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>'
        },
        "preDrawCallback" : function() {
            // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
            if (!responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column) {
                responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#datatable_fixed_column_GroupEnquiry'), breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        "rowCallback" : function(nRow) {
            responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        "drawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
            responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column.respond();
        }       

    });

    otable.state.clear(); //to clear saveState, but only work if the page is load for the second time

    // Apply the filter
    $("#datatable_fixed_column_GroupEnquiry thead th input[type=text]").on( 'keyup change', function () {

        otable
            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();

    } );
});
```

**Situation**

The tables work perfectly with `saveState`. When user go to specific page (example: page 5), and click on view detail (load new detail page), and click back button (load previous page with table) and the table still stays on the current page (page 5). This is what I want.

**Problem**

When user clicks on the navigation and redirect to the table, it still loads the table with previous state (which is in page 5) instead of display the 1st page and without any search filter.

**Expected result**

Supposed when user click on navigation and load table, the table should be display fresh state (on page 1 and without any search filter).

**Attempt**:

I placed `otable.state.clear()` as the code provided above, to clean the saveState of the table when user clicked navigation and display table. But it behaves weirdly, it only works on the second clicks on navigation.

I have no idea how actually saveState works and it is necessary to give unique id (`#datatable_fixed_column_GroupEnquiry`) for each table? I have more than 20 tables in different pages. How to clean saveState on specific button (navigation) and loads a fresh state table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else searching for the solution, this helped for me. 
I had the case that i wanted to clear the state when I access the dataTable with a link or pressed on refresh.

I put the followed piece of code, above the init of the dataTable inside the $(document).ready()

```
if (performance.navigation.type != 2){ //checks if page is accessed through a link or refresh
    var table = $('#orderHistoryTable').DataTable();
    table.state.clear();
    table.destroy(); // need to destroy the table, I don't know why..
}
```

Comment: Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. 
Please use the PerformanceNavigationTiming interface instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type